# Authentication for salesforce community site without user in service provider org

Tags: authentication, salesforce, single-sign-on, salesforce-communities

Authentication for salesforce community site without user in service provider org
I want to authenticate a community site page using sso but don't want to create a user in service provider salesforce org.

How can we achieve it any suggestion ?

What I have tried till now:

One Identity Provider Org Setup - salesforce1

Service provider Org - salesforce2

I have one community page in salesforce2 org that I want to access using salesforce1 credentials but don't want this user record in salesforce2 org.

Is it feasible?

I found one article but not sure how to implement it.

`https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.sso_sites.htm&type=5`